# Can I use method as Column in Sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    def __init(self,first_name,last_name):
         self.first_name = first_name
         self.last_name = last_name 

    _fullname = Column("fullname", String)

    @property
    def fullname(self):
        return self.first_name + self.last_name

    @fullname.setter
    def set_fullname(self, fullname):
         self.first_name = fullname[0:2]
         self.last_name = fullname[2:]
```

I wish when I save a User， fullname will be called and the return value will be save to column fullname in db, and set_fullname will be called after the object is loaded from database.

I hope a property with get/set method can be configure as a column by sqlalchemy

Comment: You probably have your reasons, but still: why do you need to materialize the "fullname"? And are your first names really constrained to 2 characters only? Is this being done against an existing table? The way I see it you could reverse your idea: create getters and setters out of *first_name* and *last_name*, which handle updating the *fullname*.

Comment: what i want is like these, a class has property a,b,c,d,e,f,g. abc will be save as column, and d,e,f,g will be transfer to a json and save to the database. so i wish there will be a solution can called when the the object is saved, update and load.

Comment: You can twiddle with the data just [before inserts/updates using events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_insert), at least. Of course you could enforce such things in the DB using triggers. There's the [reconstructor](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/constructors.html) as well, but that's just the other half. I'm still fairly certain that this is an XY problem. Then there's the [composite column](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/composites.html), but that's actually the opposite of how you're looking at it.

Comment: Thank for your help. but it still have two problem.

Comment: first, the listener and reconstructor can't affect the subclass. Because I plan to keep subclass in one table, and different value will be save as json. do i need to write reconstructor  method and add listener for every subclass? I plan to create one method and do the configuration at super class

Comment: second one, if I change d,e,f,g, I need to trigger the change manually? is there any automatically solution?